# Google Tag Manager - tag to copy previous page source/medium

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem where our 3rd party payment system is changing our source/medium to referral. Is there a way of setting up a tag to that the payment page will have the same source/medium of the previous page?

Comment: If your payment gateway is on a separate domain in should be enough to add that domain to your referral exclusion list in the property settings (does not work retroactively).

Comment: But would that just attribute it back to direct?@EikePierstorff

Comment: No, that would keep the original source, if any, although the documentation on this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll back my comment up with Google's [official documentation on the referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en):

> Third-party payment processors 
>   A common use for this feature is to
>   prevent third-party shopping carts from starting second sessions. When
>   the third-party shopping cart is in the exclusion list, a user will no
>   longer initiate a new session, and won't be counted as a referral when
>   they return to your order-confirmation page after checking out on the
>   third-party site.

So this is a suggested use case by Google.